# PUT operation response not being saved in Core Data Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to authenticate a user with github using RestKit and saving the response back to Core data to hang on to the oauth token. The response is coming back with a 200 or 201 which is good, but nothing is saved back to the context. I assume that there is something small that I am missing, but I can't figure it out. Here's what's going on:

This happens in viewDidLoad

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];
RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"SLAuthentication" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

NSString *clientID = [(SLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] clientID];



[entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id" : @"tokenID", @"url" : @"url", @"token" : @"oauthToken", @"note" : @"note"}];

entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"tokenID"];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping method:RKRequestMethodPUT pathPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/authorizations/clients/%@", clientID] keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

Here's where the request is made

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore] mainQueueManagedObjectContext];

NSString *secret = [(SLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] clientSecret];

NSString *clientID = [(SLAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] clientID];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:userName password:pass];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setRequestSerializationMIMEType:@"application/json"];



[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] putObject:nil path :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/authorizations/clients/%@", clientID] parameters:@{@"client_secret": secret, @"scopes" : @[@"repo"]} success:nil failure:nil];


//Flush the username and password so that we aren't storing them anymore.
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient clearAuthorizationHeader];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"SLUser"];
NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *users = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

[[users firstObject] setUserName:userName];

[context save:&error];
```

But nothing comes back. The description of the API is here: http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#get-or-create-an-authorization-for-a-specific-app

Comment: Also it looks like the response is being mapped into the correct object, but the entity isn't being saved at the end. Any thoughts? Ignore The fetch request and save at the end, RestKit should still save correct?

Answer (score 0):

The response is asynchronous so you need to implement the success (and failure) blocks on the put request and run your fetch request there. But, your fetch is for a different entity so it isn't clear how you're checking / using the returned authentication object.

If you still have issues, turn on trace logging for the mapping to get additional information and check for errors returned to the failure block.

Comment: Even if the success/failure blocks are null, shouldn't the entity be saved when the request returns? And ignore the checks at the bottom, those were from other things that haven't been removed yet.

Comment: Not when the request returns - it doesn't block till completion. The save will happen if they are nil but you won't know when it happens...

Comment: Doing a fetch request in the success block works, but trying to get that object in a different view controller returns nothing. Am I supposed to be using a specific managedObjectContext?

Comment: For UI you should always be using the main queue MOC from the object store.